# getting a file with a certain extension from a directory

Tags: c, file, operating-system

Iv'e encountered this piece of code that suppose to return me the extension of a file:

```
char* getFileNameExt(const char *filename) {
  char *dot = strrchr(filename, '.');
  if(!dot || dot == filename) return "";
  return dot + 1;
}
```

But, when I tried to use it to extract the extension of a files who are inside an argument directory I get an conflicting types for ‘getFileNameExt’ error.

Here is where I use it:

```
void getCFile(User* user, int userNum, char directory[LEN],char filePath[LEN]){
  DIR* pDir = opendir(directory);
  if (pDir == NULL){
    sysCallFailureProcedure();
  }
  struct dirent* pDirent;
  while((pDirent = readdir(pDir))!=NULL) {
    if ((pDirent->d_type == DT_DIR) && (strcmp(pDirent->d_name, ".") != 0)
        && (strcmp(pDirent->d_name, "..") != 0)){
      char dir[MAX_LENGTH]={};
      strcpy(dir,directory);
      int length = strlen(dir);
      if (dir[length] != '/') {
        strcat(dir, "/");
      }
      strcat(dir, pDirent->d_name);
      getCFile(user, userNum, dir, filePath);
    } else if (pDirent->d_type == DT_REG) {
      const char* extension = getFileNameExt(pDirent->d_name);
      if(strcmp(extension,"c") == 0) {
        strcpy(filePath, pDirent->d_name);
        strcpy(user[userNum].cfileDirPath, directory);
        break;                         // todo: maybe remove break.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The purpose of all of this code is to extract the path to the user's cFileDirPath, if one exists.

Comment: "I get an conflicting types for ‘getFileNameExt’ error." --> what file name was used at that time?  Was it `"."` or `".."`?

Comment: getFileName is the function above that suppose to get only the extension of any file.

Comment: There is no `getFileName()` function.

Comment: you are right. I meant getFileNameExt

Comment: 1) Code lacks buffer overflow detection in `strcat(dir, pDirent->d_name);`.  An overflow may contribute to troubles.  2) `dir[length] != '/'` is always true.  Its use is unclear.

Comment: After `getCFile(user, userNum, dir, filePath);` recursive call, it seems unclear why code just iterates to the next  file entry.  Should not some decision be made here?

Comment: It also looks inside the subdirectories of the main one for the c file.

Comment: elihar, yes but if a ".c"` match was found, why continue looking?  IAC, the role of `user/userNum` is unclear vs a simple destination `char *` pointer.  This post would benefit with a [mcve].

Comment: What is the actual error message?